# Add new text to div every time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been looking into AngularJS a bit, and I want to know it there's a way - without making the page refresh, to keep adding more text to a div every time the button is pressed, using AngularJS? I know this can be done with text and submit buttons, but I don't know how it can be done with just buttons, here's an example.

```
<button>Word</button> <!-- Every time this is clicked, add 'word' to the div 'text' without refreshing -->

<div id="text" class="text">
<!-- Write word here as many times as the button is pressed -->
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kgmw5rqp/

Comment: Please add a little more details to your question. What have you tried so far? The javascript field in the created `jsfiddle` is empty. Which version of angular do you want to use (1/2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **AngularJS** your can do it using `ng-model` with `ng-repeat`

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9820/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        texts : []
    }

    $scope.addText = function(text){
        $scope.data.texts.push(text)
    }   
});

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addText(data.text)">Add text</button>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.text">
    <div ng-repeat="text in data.texts">{{text}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/kgmw5rqp/1/)

You can do this using pure JavaScript. Please see the below JS

```
function addWord() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML + "word";
}
```

Invoke the function `addWord()` by setting the `onclick` of the button as follows

```
<button onclick="addWord()">Word</button>
```